# SparkJava: Pages don't update until restart

Tags: java, spark-java

I am working on a web application with SparkJava and I'm wondering how to setup my development environment so I don't need to restart the server to update pages. I'm using the Velocity template engine.

I assume either Spark or Velocity load the pages on start for a performance boost. That's alright for production but I'd like to be able to edit the pages and be able to view my changed pages immediately.

Comment: Are you editing the web page files with a different editor than the IDE you use to start the application?

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez No, I'm using IntelliJ for both.

Comment: well that's an IDE problem then. If you use Eclipse, for example, the files are automatically replicated to the target folder and the changes get updated without restart.

Comment: How are the velocity files packaged? Are they inside the application running JAR?

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35796389/3109776